# ClickableSpan from XML?

Tags: kotlin, popup

I'm creating a book app in Kotlin/Android Studio. With the data stored in XML, when I press a certain word I need a window to be displayed with the information, how could I do this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4dfv.jpg)

My application is working, I need to add that function, to define the words that are in another language, so that it is more comprehensive.
*the entire book is in XML
I use 2 spinners to access the sub-books and chapters.